# AsyncHttpClient with ThreadPoolExecutor to know when all tasks are finished?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I am using `AsyncHttpClient` to get some JSONs.  My method will parse through the JSON and will fire another get request, so I don't actually know how many threads are running. After some searching, I think I could use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to know when all my threads are finished, so I can write to a database. How will the executor know I submitted a job if I am using `AsyncHttpClient.get()`?

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
int limit = 20;
BlockingQueue<Runnable> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(limit);
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
                        new ThreadPoolExecutor(limit, limit, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, q);
client.setThreadPool(executor);
parseSilo(url, context); // this fires client.get() ... as it encounters urls in JSON feed
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      Log.e(TAG, executor.getTaskCount() + " tasks left");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see where you submit your job to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Sample code:

```
executor.execute(new Runnabale() {
    public void run() {
       // your job code
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you are overriding the default `ThreadPoolExecuter` of `AsyncHttpClient` so it will be used it when issuing a request (e.g. `get`), it should work without explicitly sending anything to the `executor`

You can also override the method `terminated()` instead of looping until all tasks finish.

Comment: Right, so maybe my question was not clear. How will the executor know I submitted a job if I am using AsyncHttpClient.get()?

Comment: You are overriding the default `ThreadPoolExecuter` of `AsyncHttpClient` so it will be use it when issuing a request

Comment: Ok I think I understand now, but is this bad since AsyncHttpClient.get() is an asynchronous call?

Comment: I do not know what you mean but *is this bad*? `AsynchHttpClient` uses `ThreadPoolExecuter` in order to have `asynch` methods